# How do I set the correct constraints for the table view below?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I need help setting the correct constraints for the table view below. Heres the code for the constraints.[image]. I am trying to show a 60 by 60 image view with a text by the right; please have a look at Tvtable view cell file.
Project link: https://github.com/lexypaul13/Trending-Tv-Shows/

```
private func set() {
    addSubview(tvImage)
    addSubview(tvName)
    
    tvImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tvName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let padding: CGFloat    = 12

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tvImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        tvImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
        tvImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
        tvImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
        
        tvName.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        tvName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tvImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 24),
        tvImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        tvImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first problem is that you should place the subviews of a table view cell into it's content view, so use:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(tvImage)
self.contentView.addSubview(tvName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:-

Here you added "tvImage" & "tvName" in tableviewCell.

```
addSubview(tvImage)
addSubview(tvName)
```

and setting the constraint with "contentView"(shown below)

```
tvImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
```

Solution:-

You just have to add "tvImage" & "tvName" in "tableviewCell's contentView"

```
contentView.addSubview(tvImage)
contentView.addSubview(tvName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Among other issues...

```
    // add subviews to contentView, not self!
    contentView.addSubview(tvImage)
    contentView.addSubview(tvName)
    
    tvImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tvName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let padding: CGFloat    = 12

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tvImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        tvImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
        tvImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),
        tvImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60),

        // constrain to contentView, not self!
        //tvName.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        tvName.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        tvName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tvImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 24),
        
        // these two lines should be tvName, not tvImage!
        //tvImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        //tvImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        tvName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
        tvName.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks but it produces a circular image. How do I resolve it ?

Comment: @MayowaPaul - well, *your* code in `class TvImage` is producing the circular image. If you don't want it round, change that code.